# Grouping array into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, split, append

There is one array that contains `appointmentID` (first value) and `supperBillID` (second value) separated by a comma. The `AppointmentID` will be unique but `superBillID` can be the same in consecutive position only. What I want is one array that contains all the `appointmentID` values, which have same `billingID`, separated by comma.

I wrote the below code but I'm not getting the proper output:

```
var fg = ['10000021,23', '10000022,23', '10000023,24', '10000024,25', '10000025,25', '10000026,25', '10000027,26', '10000028,27'];
var tab = [];
var gbl = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < fg.length; i++, gbl++) {
    var vb = fg[gbl].split(',')[1]; // Will use try catch here
    var mainAr = fg[gbl].split(',')[0];

    for (var j = i + 1; j < fg.length; j++) {
        if (vb == fg[j].split(',')[1]) {
            mainAr = mainAr + ',' + fg[j].split(',')[0];
            gbl++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        tab.push(mainAr, vb);
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
var input = ['10000021,23', '10000022,23', '10000023,24', '10000024,25', '10000025,25', '10000026,25', '10000027,26', '10000028,27'];
```

Expected Output:

```
output = ['10000021,10000023',23]
         ['10000023',24]
         ['10000024,10000025,10000026',25]
         ['10000027',26]
         ['10000028',27]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a first step you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the `appointmentdID` values into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (to avoid duplicates values for `appointmentID`) using `billingID` as the key to group.

Then, you can [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the previously generated object to the final desired structure. Here, I'm going to assume you want one of two possible outputs: **A)** an array of arrays as you showed last, or **B)** an array of strings with the style of the input.

```js
var input = ['10000021,23', '10000022,23', '10000023,24', '10000024,25', '10000025,25', '10000026,25', '10000027,26', '10000028,27'];

let output = input.reduce((acc, str) =>
{
    const [appointmentID, billingID] = str.split(",");
    acc[billingID] = acc[billingID] || new Set();
    acc[billingID].add(appointmentID);
    return acc;
}, {});

// Map to array of arrays:
let out1 = Object.entries(output).map(([k, v]) => [[...v].join(","), +k]);
console.log("Array of arrays", out1);

// Map to array of strings:
let out2 = Object.entries(output).map(([k, v]) => [...v, k].join(","));
console.log("Array of strings", out2);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another alternative, not so generic, based on the assumption: "*The `AppointmentID` will be unique but `superBillID` can be the same **in consecutive position only***" could be:

```js
var input = ['10000021,23', '10000022,23', '10000023,24', '10000024,25', '10000025,25', '10000026,25', '10000027,26', '10000028,27'];
let output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    const [appointmentID, billingID] = input[i].split(",");
    const len = output.length - 1;

    if (output[len] && output[len][1] === +billingID)
        output[len][0] += "," + appointmentID;
    else
        output.push([appointmentID, +billingID]);
}

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array with each `supperBillID` as a key in the accumulator. If the `supperBillID` already exists, update the `0` index. Else, add the key to the accumulator and set it to an array. Get values as an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var fg = ['10000021,23', '10000022,23', '10000023,24', '10000024,25', '10000025,25', '10000026,25', '10000027,26', '10000028,27'];

const merged = fg.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const [appId, billId] = o.split(',');
  if (acc[billId])
    acc[billId][0] += `,${appId}`;
  else
    acc[billId] = [appId, billId]
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the array to a convenient array of objects and then reduce the array according to the condition described

```js
const input = [
  "10000021,23",
  "10000022,23",
  "10000023,24",
  "10000024,25",
  "10000025,25",
  "10000026,25",
  "10000027,26",
  "10000028,27"
];

const dataset = input.map(item => {
  const nodes = item.split(",");

  return {
    appointmentid: nodes[0],
    superbillid: nodes[1]
  };
});

const output = dataset.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  const item = accumulator.find(
    element => element[element.length - 1] === current.superbillid
  );

  if (item !== undefined) {
    item.unshift(current.appointmentid);
  } else {
    accumulator.push([current.appointmentid, current.superbillid]);
  }

  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

To get the array of strings you could try using map on each array item like this

`const recipient = output.map(item => item.join(',')));`

This will return

```
[
  "10000022,10000021,23",
  "10000023,24",
  "10000026,10000025,10000024,25",
  "10000027,26",
  "10000028,27"
]
```